# "The block is missing }" when I don't close table and tbody tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Razor (C#) syntax to create a table within a while loop, but unless I do `</tbody>` and `</table>` within the first statement, I get an error

> The block is missing }...

at the `if` and `for` statement. How can I fix this and why does it simply not allow me to let the code run without closing a tag?

```
@if (Model.Any())
{
    string currentWaiter = "lex luthor > superman";
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (currentWaiter.Equals("lex luthor > superman"))
        {
            currentWaiter = item.name;
            <table class="tablesorter">
                <thead>
                    <!-- ... some info ... -->
                </thead>
            </table>
            <table class="tablesorter">
                <thead>
                    <!-- ... some info ... -->
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="OpenTables">
                            @item.method
                        </td>
                        <td class="OpenTables">
                            @item.total.ToString("#,##0.00");
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        }
        else if (currentWaiter.Equals(item.name))
        {
            //magic and whatnot
        }
        else
        {
            //abracadabra!
            </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: you need to close the `<table>` and the `<tbody>` in the if block.

Comment: @user1666620 that's not an option. But...

Comment: @CodeCaster 's solution (other post which I couldn't find my self) seamed to solve the issue. I hope he'll answer here, so I can give him the points he deserves :)

Comment: what do you mean "not an option"? you do know how if/else if /else blocks work?

Comment: @NemanjaT no need for points (I have plenty of them), I just like linking related questions. Please leave yours up so that people who search the web using your phrasing can find the answers in the duplicate. :-)

Comment: @user1666620 yet the duplicate post that codecaster pointed out worked out :) I know how if/else blocks work, but closing tag from one block causes an error from the opening block from the other one